# Deobfuscate proguard for AOSP application

Tags: android, proguard, android-source

I am building an application in AOSP code and i have enabled pro-guard for this application by adding pro-guard flags in mk files, and code compiled fine and generated APK in the /out directory.

Flags :

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags $(call all-named-files-under,proguard.*flags,$(BASE_DIR))
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := full obfuscation
```

But the application crashes, but i don't find the mapping.txt file in the out directory. Where will i find the mapping file to decode the crash ? or what is the right way to decode the crash log for AOSP applications when pro-guard is enabled ?

crash logs:

```
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.dialer, PID: 3081
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.incallui.call.q.Ry()' on a null object reference
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.i.q._f(Unknown Source:50)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.i.q.a(Unknown Source:279)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.incall.impl.j.a(Unknown Source:16)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.InCallActivity.pU(Unknown Source:287)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.InCallActivity.a(Unknown Source:0)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.Ka.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:2)
12-20 07:23:12.599  3081  3081 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.incallui.Ka.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:2)
```

Comment: What means `defusticate` and where is the stack-trace? One does not necessarily need a mapping file; in most cases it should be obvious what it cannot resolve. Besides, one can obfuscate the same classes in a regular application, where there will be a mapping in a known location.

Comment: to decrypt the logs files. Attached the stack-trace for reference. @MartinZeitler

Comment: im searching for the location of mappings.txt in AOSP code. the location is not know yet.My question is about the location of mapping file only

Comment: find out -type f -name "mapping.txt"